# Check for Reachability in viewDidAppear or AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using AlamoreFire and checking for network reachability in two of the app's view controllers in the viewDidAppear method of both. But sometimes when the network is found the view controller collection view loads twice.
I am guessing that maybe the Reachability should be put in one place only in the entire app.

What is the best and cleanest way to implement Reachability when you have multiple view controllers to check?
I would like to use the NetworkReachabilityManager from AlamoFire.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a double up on a closure resultHandler anywhere?

Comment: @dkw5877 I know about the classes, my question is where in the code should be more appropriate to implement it, AppDelegate or in each ViewDidAppear method?

Comment: I've used @Velix007 approach in apps where I did not have an offline mode. Monitor for status changes in the app delegate and then present a internet connection view controller from the top most view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Normally with Reachability you'd have some sort of error view on top of the screen, don't worry if the background is trying to load or not.

Create a container view and in viewDidLoad()

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
        self.errorView.isHidden = true
    } else {
        self.errorView.isHidden = false
    }
```

That solves your problem and helps with UX.

Comment: Thanks Velix007, in fact my app does not crash because I am using Alamofire.request(url).validate() and already checking in there. I could overlap my activity indicator spinning with an errorView as you say. I just wasn't sure it was the "correct" way to do it.

Comment: I'm sure there are mixed feelings about it, but from a UX perspective and with the decent experience I have, it's not that bad at all, its better than making your user think the app is messed up because a screen is load 2x, 3x times.
errorView ftw.

Answer (score 0):

I have my method below. To be more direct to your question though, I would not check for connection in either.

**Example:** I get all the way to the apps first network call and then turn my wifi on.

**Problem:** My app fails even though nothing that needed wifi in the App was used.

**My Method:** I can understand checking for a network connection on the login page, but besides that, I would put it into your network. If a network call fails, check the connection and then relate to the user whether the call failed because of the server or because of the network.

This is what I use for Reachability:

```
import Foundation

/// This class is designed to check if the network is connected.
open class Reachability {

    /// This function will hit two urls that should never be totally down to see if the device is connected
    /// If either url connects, this returns true
    ///
    /// - Parameter resultHandler: returns the result of the connection existing as a Bool in a resultHandler
    class func isConnectedToNetwork(_ resultHandler: @escaping (_ isTrue: Bool) -> Void) {
        let urlA = URL(string: "https://google.com/")
        let urlB = URL(string: "https://baidu.com/")

        Reachability.fetchURL(urlA!) { isTrue in
            if isTrue {
                print("NETWORK STATUS: \(isTrue)")
                resultHandler(isTrue)
            } else {
                Reachability.fetchURL(urlB!, resultHandler: resultHandler)
            }
        }
    }

    /// Hits a URL in order to see if the device can connect to it
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - url: the url to request
    ///   - resultHandler: returns whether the url was successfully retrieved or not
    class func fetchURL(_ url:URL, resultHandler: @escaping (_ isTrue: Bool) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        request.timeoutInterval = 10.0

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    resultHandler(true)
                } else {
                    resultHandler(false)
                }
            } else {
                resultHandler(false)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Then anywhere in code you can call it like so:

```
Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() { isConnected in
    if isConnected {
        //Do something when connected
    } else {
        //Do something when not connected
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. BTW how do you monitor for network status changes? How would you post a notification if it changes?

Comment: I do my checks in my network calls, so I can always tell the user why it failed when it fails. if I need to take action accordingly, I do so at that point in time.

Comment: So if you have a table view it would check it for every cell when loading ?

Comment: Only if and when a network call failed. I have been testing my App for over 6 months, and it works like a charm in all circumstances I personally can put it through.

Comment: Why would you waste resources checking if you have a connection before a call fails? The only situation I can think of would be in the viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear of the loginViewController if you didn't want the user to attempt to login before they were told to get their device connected to the network. With Data being something that is far overpriced in my opinion, I desire to minimize that usage on my users where possible even when minimal results are found.

Comment: How do you tell if you are connected to wifi or 3G using your method?

Comment: I don't using my method. Could you share me a link of a method of finding this. I once tried to figure that out in my early developer days and never came to a conclusion. It would be an interesting read.

Comment: I use Alamofire.request(url).validate() and the app already understand if there is or not network connection while trying to get the url. At this point I think Reachability could be inserted in one place only, just to show an alertView to the user, wherever the user is inside the app (in any of the view controllers).

Comment: To put reachability it in the viewDidLoad of all view controllers seemed redundant.

Comment: @Giovanni I have not used Alamofire, and I am aware that it is a respectable library. My method is just what I chose without using any 3rd party libraries.